# API POST call with large model, need some guidance

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, api

I have a fairly large form (50 fields) and I need to pass it into an API call.

Doing it in the javascript file would be pretty large to serialize all the data on the form into the proper model.

Is it possible to call the controller, and use the model from that to pass it through to the api url?

Basically I want to know an easy way to take my form data and turn it into serialized data based on my model.

thanks!

EDIT: Easy meaning that I don't have to take each form input and create my model with them

My code now is basically this below, but I would need to fill out a bunch of fields (I haven't tried it any other way)

```
 $("#submit").click(function () {
            var name = $("#Name").val();
            var address = $("#Address").val();
            var dob = $("#DOB").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:49493/api/Values",
                type: "Post",
                data: JSON.stringify([name, address, dob]), 
                //instead of 3 fields, I would have 50
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) { },
                error: function () { alert('error'); }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you show us your code as it exists, as well as what you'd like to do with it (showing us both approaches through code?) Also, what means 'easy'? Easy is quite a subjective term.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a function that you can use $("#myForm").serialize()

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
            var myData = $("#myForm").serialize() 
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:49493/api/Values",
                type: "Post",
                data: myData, 
                //instead of 3 fields, I would have 50
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) { },
                error: function () { alert('error'); }
            });
        });
```

(Although a 50 form field sounds quite large. You might want to reconsider your design, but perhaps there is a valid use case)

Comment: Wouldn't @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) not render correct on the client because it happens server side and the Model wouldn't have the populated form values at that point?

Answer (score 0):

A javascript MV* framework can be helpful here (I'm most familiar with angular). With angular, you can define a binding between your UI elements and the underlying javascript model representation (which can be sent to your Web API with the $http service).

Here is a language agnostic way to iterate over elements and build a model. It was done quick and dirty, and there is much room for improvement (i.e. using addEventListener, attachEvent, then onclick, etc.) -- but jquery handles much of this for you, so would suggest to stick with using that. This could easily be converted over to jQuery... The javascript iterates over input elements and adds them to a model object. This object can then be sent over AJAX if desired. The example just outputs it to a div placeholder.

http://jsfiddle.net/T9MyZ/

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("submitMe").onclick = function () {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var model = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        var elem = inputs[i];
        model[elem.name] = elem.value;
    }

    document.getElementById("jsonText").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(model);
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="text" name="address"><br>
<input type="text" name="dob"><br>
<button id="submitMe">Submit</button>
<br>
<div id="jsonText"></div>
```